# pycharm pip freeze issue

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm doing a project in pycharm and I want to do pip freeze,but the result is a file with all python's lib and not just my project's depedncies.
I've noticed that my project is without venv.
I created one I did the pip freeze inside of it and got the same result.
How do I resolve this? how do I create a pip freeze with just my project's dependencies?

thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate your virtual env.

```
# Create a virtual env
[...]$ python -m venv venv

# Activate your virtualenv
[...]$ source venv/bin/python

# Install your deps:
(venv) [...]$ pip install Django

# Freeze your env:
(venv) [...]$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Content of `requirements.txt`:

```
asgiref==3.5.0
Django==4.0.2
sqlparse==0.4.2
```

Comment: i activated the venv via pycharm but it did'nt help, for now i did what @Franz Kurt suggested and it produced a very very short requirements file. i hope it will do the trick.wiil update if not.

Answer (score 0):

The pip freeze code only saves the packages that are installed with pip install in your environment.

```
pip freeze # all installed libs
```

Instead you can use pipreqs

```
pip install pipreqs
pipreqs /home/project/location
```

The file requirements will be like that

```
wheel==0.23.0
Yarg==0.1.9
docopt==0.6.2
```

Reference: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs

Comment: i did and it really produce a requirements file. avery very short one. i hope it will do the trick.will update if not.